# What happened to Lady Dracula in Superman?

Tags: dc, superman

In [Superman #180](http://www.comicvine.com/superman-180-the-house-of-dracula/4000-113818/), Superman defeats Count Rominoff (Dracula) and his schemes. However, at the end we see that his wife (Countess Dracula) remains on their château.

What happens to her? Has she appeared in any other books since then?

This story appeared around 2002, if that is any help.

Comment: It would appear she was never heard from again. Then, there were various Crises and 52 became an important number and she may never have existed. Then, The Flash changed the past and everything was all differenty and 52 became a New important number. Then, all the past versions of everything reemerged and fought each other, which somehow made continuity not matter anymore. The end?

Comment: Was Flashpoint (assuming you are referring to that) the chain of events where everything got changed and resulted in the New 52 (reboot) series? @Politank-Z

Comment: One of them. Identity Crisis --> Infinite Crisis --> Final Crisis --> Flashpoint --> Convergence. I may have missed a reboot in there somewhere. Post-Convergence, we have DC You! which I take to be DC throwing its hands up and saying "How about we just write comics and you buy them and we don't worry about how they connect to each other or the past, OK?"

Answer (score 1):

This synopsis for ["The House of Dracula"](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_180) makes no mention of Countess Dracula. It mentions a maid, named Elizabeth, who is later revealed to be a vampire and attacks Jimmy Olsen.

Assuming that is who you thought was Countess Dracula, the wiki reports her as a `single appearance` character.